# Responsive Navbar: Nav List items disappearing in 320px width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive navigation bar using media queries. **The Nav Ul Li items are displaying in other widths breakpoints specified using media queries except for 320px.**

I think something is wrong with CCS cascading property, however I cannot pick out the reason why the nav items are not showing.

****Here is full screen width:****
[image]

**Here is the 320px screen width**
[image]

Full html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Delivery Motion!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    // Grab the pull (extra menu icon) div and when clicked event handler will bring menu (the old actual menu).
    $(function() {
      var pull        = $('#pull');
      menu        = $('nav ul');
      menuHeight  = menu.height();

      $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
      });
    });
// if the window is resized greater than 320px remove the display none attribute from the menu (actual older menu).
    $(window).resize(function(){
      var w = $(window).width();
      if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
          menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
    </script>


   </head>
   <body>
     <nav class="clearfix">
       <ul class="clearfix">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
      </nav>
   </body>
</html>
```

Full CSS code

```
* {
  margin: 0%;
}
body {
    background-color: #ece8e5;
}

nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #283744;
}

nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right
    /*border: 2px solid;*/
}
nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
nav a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 40px;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #283744;*/
}
nav li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}

/*the menu will have brighter color when it is in :hover or :active state*/
nav a:hover, nav a:active {
    background-color: #8c99a4;
}
/*extra link will be hidden (for the desktop screen)*/
nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

/*When the screen size is max 600px the nav ul width will be 50%*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
        border-right: 1px solid #576979;
    }
    nav a {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        text-indent: 25px;
    }
}
/*how the navigation is displayed when the screen get smaller by 480px or lower (so this is our second breakpoint)*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    nav {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }



    nav a#pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: url('../img/burger-bar.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
}

}

/*Smartphone*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is what that code is doing - #pull - <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a> now you click the menu and you get a drop down mobile menu yes?

Comment: yes. that is correct using JQuery

Comment: Are you asking for the CSS or do you need the script too ?

Comment: I think the salient code to share here is your @media queries then as that is what is affecting your break points and there may be a conflict from one to another, especially if you are using sass and calling a media querie into a file that is already being called in to a media querie.

Comment: The pull div is hidden and only show using jquery. I follow this tutorial, look their last step: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/

Comment: Any ideas? I can get it to work fine when I follow the steps. However when changing the design layout for my project, i move the ul to float: right, the ul is disappeared in the 320px width

Comment: @Code2016 Is this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y35xjhfg/) helping you ? Now you have to set the visibility to "hidden" again in the css, and use JS to make it visible/hidden again

Comment: Hey im not sure what you changed and where im suppose to add visibility hidden?